# WPF and treeview: tricks with Items

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have some questions about treeview in WPF.

1. How can I change header of selected item?
2. How can I add child Items to selected item?

Comment: What does your current XAML look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MVVM.  In your `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, bind `Header` and `ItemsSource` to properties in your view model which implement change notification.  Now any changes you make to those properties will be reflected in the `TreeView`.

If you're not using MVVM and data binding to populate the `TreeView`, you're wasting a lot of effort.

Answer (score 2):

Robert is right, you should use MVVM and data binding. The tutorial that IMHO explained it best is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx)